# How to send and receive value using ERC-1155

Tags: nft, erc-1155, solidity-0.8.x

I am relatively new to solidity and blockchain. I want to develop a smart contract that sends values and another contract that accepts one using ERC-1155 tokens.Can any of you please help me out with this. It would be great if you could show me dummy contracts that implements these. I went through the documentation provided by EIP and understood the functioning from a theoretical point. But I can't figure out how to implement in code. So it would be helpful if I could see some sample code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ERC-1155 can be a bit overwhelming after looking through the EIP proposals. Take a look at this sample implementation from Opensea https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-erc1155/blob/master/contracts/MyLootBox.sol

It should help you with a close to real-life implementation of the ERC-1155 protocol.